# How to get all the child element name along with their parent element name from XML using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get all the child element name along with their parent element name from XML using C#.

My XML like in below

```
<entry>
    <id>4444</id>
    <name>4444</name>
    <author>
        <id>1111</id>
        <name>ishu</name>
        <uri>
            <url>www.youtube.com</url>
        </uri>
     </author>
</entry>
```

I want the tag name like below,

```
entry.id
entry.name
entry.author.id
entry.author.name
entry.author.uri.url
```

Is possible to get the tag name like above? Please provide me the C# code if Possible.

Comment: Yes.  Need to see more of the xml file.  Using Xml Linq it is very simple

Comment: Can you explain it briefly?

Comment: Better to show as an example.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using `XDocument` and iterate through all `Elements`

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        Dictionary<string, string> nodelist = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        nodelist.Add("entry", "entry");
        foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Element("entry").Descendants())
        {
            if (!nodelist.ContainsKey(element.Name.ToString()))
                nodelist.Add(element.Name.ToString(),
                    (nodelist.ContainsKey(element.Parent.Name.ToString())? nodelist[element.Parent.Name.ToString()] : element.Parent.Name.ToString())+"."+ element.Name.ToString());

            if (!element.HasElements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ nodelist[element.Parent.Name.ToString()]}.{element.Name}");
            }               
        }
```